# Drone moving to the right when increasing throttle

Tags: first-person-view

I recently built an FPV drone using a JHEMCU F4 flight controller and ReadytoSky 4-in-1 ESC. However, I'm encountering a problem where the drone drifts to the right when throttling up slightly. I've already tried swapping motors, but the issue persists. Here's what I've tried so far:

1. Calibrated ESCs( by increasing the motor rpm in betaflight while the battery is not connected. Then connected the battery and then lowered the motor rpm to 0)
2. Performed accelerometer  calibration
   Despite these efforts, the problem persists. Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like your drone wasn't quite level when you calibrated the accelerometer. Or perhaps the flight controller board isn't quite level in the drone.

Calibrate the accelerometer again, but this time with a few sheets of paper under the right hand side to get it closer to level. Try it with a significant thickness first to check it actually makes a difference, then halve the amount and retry, and repeat until it's equally likely to drift in any direction.

You won't be able to trim it to hover perfectly, but you should be able to remove any bias to one direction.